# Свой шрифт в CalendarView, размер календаря и некорректное поведение в API 17

Tags: android, calendar

Несколько вопросов о `CalenarView` в одном.

Первый: как создать свой шрифт в календаре? Использовал библиотеку [(такую)](https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View),

но появилась вторая проблема: Размер календаря не увеличивается вместе с размером экрана (на планшете 10`` буквы маленькие). Как увеличить размер текста?
`android:dateTextAppearance=""`, который есть в `CalendarView` в библиотеке не работает.

Третья проблема: `CalendarView` на том же планшете 10`` API 17 долго запускается, виснет и в итоге показывает только названия недель. Не понимаю, почему так.

Буду благодарен подсказке решения хотя бы одной проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему с библиотекой решил так: скачал, добавил в проект и добавил в класс `DayView` стоку `setTextSize(мой размерчик);`

`CalendarView` на Android 4.2.2. похоже общая проблема, советуют создавать для API 17 свой класс календаря...

Может быть можно сделать `Override` `DayView` не скачивая библиотеку, через обычный `compile`? Не критично, но если есть решение - поделитесь, пжлста, в комментах.